# Recaptcha 2.0 on iOS - no submit

Tags: ios, recaptcha

recaptcha on desktop works flawlessly. However, on mobile (ios) the following is happening:

It loads a window with a tiny pic at the top and tells me that I can skip it if I don't see any images. So I hit the skip link.
Then it loads the images.. but there is no submit link/button.
What am I missing?

[image: Steps 1 and 2 side by side]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not taking the full size of the web content in consideration.

I've created a lib that enables ReCaptcha on iOS. You can take a look if it fits you: https://github.com/fjcaetano/ReCaptcha